# How to login as root from bash and do stuff

Tags: linux, bash, logging, heredoc, spawn

This is my simple bash:

```
cat test.sh

#!/bin/bash 
echo "hello"
su - root -c /path/to/script.sh <<EOF
password                              
EOF
whoami
echo "good bye"
```

But I get this error:

```
./test.sh
hello
su: must be run from a terminal
<current-user>
good bye
```

(OR)

```
cat test2.sh
#!/bin/bash 
echo "hello"
sudo su <<EOF
password                              
EOF
whoami
echo "good bye"
```

Again another error

(OR)

```
cat test3.sh
#!/bin/bash 
echo "hello"
su root <<EOF
password                              
EOF
whoami
echo "good bye"
```

again error...

when I try:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
sudo -s <<EOF
<password>
echo Now I am root
id                                                                      
echo "yes!"
EOF
whoami
echo "good bye"
```

Then the output is:

```
./script.sh
hello
[sudo] password for <user>:
```

I also changed my script to:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn sudo -s <<EOF
expect "assword for user:"
send -- "password\r"                                                                      
expect eof
```

and output is:

```
spawn sudo -s <<EOF
[sudo] password for user: 
/bin/bash: <<EOF: command not found
```

Also `which sh` output is `/bin/sh`

How can I resolve the error in these three scripts?

Comment: You should ask this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: yes I did ...but no answer

Comment: Sorry, but questions about general OS usage/scripting are not [on-topic at StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: yes...thanks..I guest there should be some guys to know how to resolve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing this kind of stuff is not safe or standard practice (in fact many consider it disasterous), it is really not a good idea to put a password in a script. A more standard approach would be simply to expect the whole script to be executed with root privileges, or just to have the script prompt for a password. You can also allow various commands to be run via sudo without a password by particular users by using the `NOPASSWD` option in `/etc/suoders`.

However, now that you are aware of the risks, it is possible to use `sudo -kS` to have sudo read the password from `stdin`:

```
sudo -kSs << EOF
password
whoami
echo "Not a good idea to have a password encoded in plain text"
EOF
```